# Is there an equivalent of DeviceNetworkInformation.NetworkAvailabilityChanged event on UWP?

Tags: networking, windows-phone, connection, uwp

I'm converting my Windows Phone 8 Silverlight to UWP and I can't find an equivalent to DeviceNetworkInformation.NetworkAvailabilityChanged event in UWP

I know that on UWP we have to use ConnectionProfile to get info about user's connection (Wifi, 3G, etc...)

```
ConnectionProfile InternetConnectionProfile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
```

But it seems that there are no events to check if the Internet becomes unavailable in ConnectionProfile object.

Does anyone know how to do this in UWP?

Thanks

Comment: I noticed that NetworkInformation has NetworkChange and NetworkAvailabilityEventArgs Classes but I wasn't able to make it work.

And also NetworkInformation only has NetworkStatusChanged event and no NetworkAvailabilityChanged event...

Can anyone please provide a sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be no equivalent of [DeviceNetworkInformation.NetworkAvailabilityChanged Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.devicenetworkinformation.networkavailabilitychanged(v=vs.105).aspx) in UWP APIs by now. But we can achieve this by combining [NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.networkstatuschanged) with [ConnectionProfile.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.networking.connectivity.connectionprofile.getnetworkconnectivitylevel).

Ref **Remarks** in [ConnectionProfile.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.networking.connectivity.connectionprofile.getnetworkconnectivitylevel):

> The recommended process for determining the network connectivity level is to register a handler for the [**NetworkStatusChanged**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.networkstatuschanged) event on the [**NetworkInformation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation) class. When a notification is received of a network status change, obtain the new connectivity level by calling the **GetNetworkConnectivityLevel** method on the profile returned by the [**GetInternetConnectionProfile**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.getinternetconnectionprofile) method. The returned network connectivity level can then be stored for later use when needed. This also ensures that the correct [**ConnectionProfile**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.networking.connectivity.connectionprofile) is checked.

Following is a simple sample:

```cs
NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged += (s) =>
{
    var profile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
    var isInternetConnected = profile != null && profile.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() == NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess;
};
```

Also you can encapsulate this into an event like in this blog: [How to react to network availability changes in Windows Store apps](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/02/04/how-to-react-to-network-availability-changes-in-windows-store-apps/).